# ngModel with a bind function not working in ng2

Tags: angular, model-binding, angular-ngmodel

If I do in a template of a component something like:

```
<input [(ngModel)]="myProperty"></input>
```

then it works, but if I do it with a function in my component it does not:

```
<input [(ngModel)]="getMyProperty()"></input>
```

[Here](https://plnkr.co/edit/j0FZIIqSH94QEoOJrmsv?p=preview) is the plunkr. Tested on RC6. Why?

Comment: Because you're trying to two-way bind to a getter method?

Comment: but this use to work on angular1, why it does not now? sorry, I do not understand.

Comment: @lqbweb This didn't work properly in angular1. It was able to get the value yes, but you couldn't write it back to the model.

Comment: alright, that could be the case yes. With this typescript you forget sometimes that you are on javascript :P

Answer (score 45):

Try this construction

```
<input [ngModel]="getMyProperty()"></input>
```

- use only square brackets.

Comment: Excellent answer

Comment: Simply you nailed it bro.

Comment: @Limitrof , doesn't `[ngModel]="getMyProperty()"` turn off two-way binding and then only updates the view when `getMyProperty()` returns different value, but won't update a component when a user updates the view?