# Pass data within a function parameter from HTML to typescript class without any event binding

Tags: angular, typescript

I am looping some objects using *ngFor in HTML, and within a div, I want to call a function having parameters and within this parameter, I also want to send some data.

**HTML**

```
<div *ngFor="let user of users">
 <div [(ngModel)]="`calDuration`(user.dateCreated)">
</div>
```

**Component class**

```
calDuration(value){

......logic here......

}
```

but i got an error :

> Parser Error: Unexpected token '=' at column 30 in [calDuration(user.dateCreated)=$event]

Comment: try out `[ngModel]="calDuration(user.dateCreated)"` as described here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39468450/ngmodel-with-a-bind-function-not-working-in-ng2

Comment: this also not works, i just want to call a function from my class and pass a value into it , can i bind a function ?

Answer (score 1):

This syntax:

`[(ngModel)]` is for two way binding:

- From a component code property to a template element AND
- From a template element (often an input box) to a component code property.

You have to bind it to a property, not a method.

You can use one-way binding instead as suggested in the comments:

```
[ngModel]="calDuration(user.dateCreated)"
```

**EDIT:**

Oh ... I may have just understood what you are trying to do. You just want to display the result of the function.

You can do this:

```
<div>{{calDuration(user.dateCreated)}}</div>
```

This will call the function and return the result in the div.

Comment: this also not works, i just want to call a function and pass a value to it , can i bind a function ?

Comment: To better answer your question, *when* do you need to call the function? If it is based on a user action (such as a button click), you can use event binding. If it is just a place in your code, you can just add the function to the `ngOnInit` method that is called whenever your component is initialized.

Comment: @RazaEllahi I may have just understood your question. See my revised answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can not use [(ngModel)] with .

[(ngModel)] is used for two way binding it won't work with function

if you are okay with once way binding use [ngModel]

if you want to do two way binding then assign some object or variable with [(ngModel)]

```
<input [ngModel]="someVaiable"></input>
```

Comment: it is simply a div not an input field, i just want to call a function and pass a value to it , can i bind a function ?

Comment: then u can use one of the life cycle hook of angular to do it.
calling function from div is not a good idea and rather bad practice